# How could process windows auth handshake (401) for ajax call in extjs 3.4?

Tags: ajax, kerberos, ntlm, extjs3

I have a store with linked proxy (use GET method) - it works fine in IE, but not working with Chrome and other modern browser's. IE can work with 401 with
`WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate TOKEN` header and send another one request with 
`Authorization: Negotiate TOKEN`, but Chrome stops on 401.
Is any best-practice to work with it? Or i should try to check and retry request manually?

Answer (score 0):

Simple set `XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials = true;` helps to solve this issue.